# JSP to Angular 2+

Tags: angular, jsp

We have a huge application written in Spring MVC and we are using JSP for UI based processing. Is it possible/feasible to upgrade from JSP to Angular? Or do we need to rewrite the entire code again?

Comment: you need to rewrite entire application

Answer (score 0):

If you have written code with architecture MVC I think the create architecture restful is a unique solution for change your big application with Angular, but also this update is very expensive.

Only with a rest architecture can you save your control code, but in many cases it depends is not enough

Answer (score 0):

If your app uses JSP there is a high probability that you are rendering on the server side with jsp tags, and probably you are not using API. If this is the case it will be easier if you rewrite your whole code from scratch.